# Code breaks as soon as I try to print a variable

Tags: procedural-programming, printing

#### Edit

I think I figured out what was wrong. Since I was adding in `Print[m]` after I ran the loop, I had to clear my variables if I wanted to run the loop again. I guess my new question is: why did I have to clear `m` and `x`? I tried to reevaluate `F[x]` to reset the function, and I tried to rerun `m = 3` after, but it just gave me strange results which I will attach below.

What happens when I rerun `F[x_] = x^2 Cos[x] + x + 3` after running the loop.

[image]

---

Original issue starts here.

I'm running a For-loop (and it needs to be a For-loop) thats supposed to do Newton's method on a function.

I'll post the parts of the code that I think are needed to get the error

```
F[x_] = x^2 Cos[x] + x + 3
m = 3

For[i = 0, i < 5, i++,     
  F'[m];
  y = F[m] + F'[m] (x - m);
  x = (0 - F[m])/(F'[m])   + m;
  Print[N[F[x]]];
  m = x
```

All of this code here works fine. The moment I add `Print[m]` or `Print[x]` to the loop, it completely breaks and I do not know why. The picture below is the code working before I add in Print[m] anywhere in the loop.

[image: Code pre-the writing of Print[m]]

Comment: The incomplete sample doesn't help. Please show us a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Also, if the `$` is really part of original code, it's obvious wrong.

Comment: oh oops its because i was doing it in math mode to format on this website. ill edit it. but yeah this is all you need to get it to work and i checked before submitting it.

Comment: If you only re-execute the `For[…]`, you just need to `Clear[m]`, and I think the reason is obvious. If you re-execute the code from the beginning, then you only need to `Clear[x]`, to understand why you need to, try `x=1; f[x_]=x; f[2]` and think about the reason.

Comment: Note carefully you need `F[x_] := x^2 Cos[x] + x + 3` with `:=` instead of just `=`. This is the standard way to define a Mathematica function of x. Read the documentation for `SetDelayed` for the reasons.